# .NetCore runtime identifier parameters ignored, MSBuild, Team City

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, teamcity

I've been having issues trying to get MSBuild to build and publish via Team City. The error message being received was as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(208, 5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'F:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\9f1e0cb4e5e5076f\myproject\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2/win-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.2' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.
```

I had thought that passing the below in the parameters to MSBuild should have resolved the issue.

```
/p:TargetFramework=netcoreapp2.2 /p:Runtimeidentifier=win-x64
```

Howvever this was not the case.

I could build/publish the project from within Visual Studio, but not via the Team City build agent.

In order to get the build agent to build/publish, I had to the project .csproj file and declare the runtime identifier:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It appears to me that either Team City is ignoring the MSBuild parameters, I have the parameters incorrect, or Visual Studio is carrying out an additional step I'm not aware of to declare the runtime identifier on publish (via WebDeploy).

I've obviously resolved the issue I was having, but this doesn't seem to be the 'correct' way of doing it. What am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I've obviously resolved the issue I was having, but this doesn't seem
>   to be the 'correct' way of doing it. What am I missing?

You may get some help from [this blog](https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2018/08/sdk-style-project-and-projectassetsjson.html#targetText=Overview%20of%20project.assets.json&targetText=Building%20requires%20the%20project.assets,when%20dotnet%20restore%20is%20executed.), ***project.assets.json*** lists all the dependencies of the project.

When you create a new `.net core` project in VS, it will create this file for you. Open it with notepad and you can find it doesn't specify runtime by default:

[image]

When you try to build it by msbuild command-line with `/p:Runtimeidentifier=win-x64`, then msbuild can't recognize that runtime since it's not defined in the `projects.assets.json` file.

An easy way to workaround this issue is to add `-restore` switch when you specify the command with a `Runtimeidentifier=xxx`.

So actually you need to pass the below parameters to msbuild, no need to manually edit the `xx.csproj` file:

```
/p:TargetFramework=xxx /p:Runtimeidentifier=xxx /restore
```

Msbuild will execute the `restore` target before it run `build` target, and the `restore` target will regenerate a new `projects.assets.json` file for win-64, see:

[image]

**Solution**:

So the correct way is to add a `restore` switch to your build command, then the build will succeed no matter which `Runtimeidentifier` you want to target. Avoid manually editing the `Runtimeidentifier` in project file!

As for why it works in VS:VS will do the restore work automatically for us when we use the Publish function(right-click project=>Publish). We can easily find a projects.assets.json for win-64 in path `ProjectFolder\obj\publish\win-x64`, so it succeeds when you publish from VS. Hmm, it's charm of IDE, right?

Answer (score 0):

Which build step (build runner) do you use to build the project? Do you have `NuGet Installer` step before it, to restore all necessary for the project dependencies? You need to add it if you use `MSBuild` or `Visual Studio` runner (as far as I know, `.NET CLI` and "dotnet build" command will restore by default and you do not need an additional step for it).